# Why does this ES6 function have this Typescript error and what can I do about it?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm running Typescript inside of VSCode and this line

```
const Felix_Reverse = ([h, ...r]) => r.length > 0 && Felix_Reverse(r) + h || h;
```

throws the following error with the `r` parameter to the embedded call to Felix_Reverse highlighted

```
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any, ...any[]]'. 
    Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[any, ...any[]]'.
```

What does this mean and how should I properly annotate the function?

Comment: I think you need to specify type of ```h``` and ```r```

Comment: I have read this error message several times and I have even less of a clue than when I hadn't. What you have should work. I guess it does in JS, but TS complains for some reason. It doesn't seem to like the destructuring would be my best guess.

Comment: Thats because `r.length > 0` does not assert that `r` is a non empty array. Destructuring however requires that (otherwise `h` could be undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that array destructuring serves two different purposes: One is to pass values like a tuple (e.g. React returns such a tuple from `useState`), on the other hand it is used to access specific parts of an array like you did. Typescript has to type both purposes correctly, thats why it types the array destructured parameter as a tuple type by default:

```
  const Felix_Reverse = ([t, ...h]: [any, ...any[]]) => /*...*/;
```

That's great on the one hand, because it prevents:

```
  Felix_Reverse([])
```

as that does not fullfill the tuple type (as that has to have a first entry of type `any`). Now thats exactly what TS complains about, it says `Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '[any, ...any[]]'.`, or in other words: It cannot guarantee that the recursive call has at least one element (actually it could, because of `r.length > 0`, but the compiler isn't that clever [yet]).

Now to resolve that, we have to turn the tuple type into an array type. Through that, even empty arrays can be passed, however then `t` might be `undefined`:

```
 const Felix_Reverse = ([h, ...r]: string[] | number[]) => r.length > 0 && Felix_Reverse(r) + h || h;
```

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I was really confused what was happening. I completely missed that `r.length` would be the culprit here as the compiler tends to have problem with indirect assertions "`r.length > 0` therefore `Felix_Reverse(r)` accepts a non-empty array"

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the argument types and return type:

```
const Felix_Reverse = ([h, ...r]: number[]): number =>
  r.length > 0 && Felix_Reverse(r) + h || h;
```

In that situation, `h` will be of type `number` and `r` of type `number[]`

Comment: `number[]` would be more appropriate.

Comment: or `string[]`, depends on the usecase.